# MySQL create arbitrary list of dates or numbers in temp table?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, loops, iterator

I'd like to create a temporary table which includes an iterator.

I would have a MySQL variable `@count` which includes the number of rows desired.

I want to import that number of rows into the table, with an iterator, so that I have rows `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

That would allow me to create the desired result set `select number from tmp`, and I could include other information where available using a `left join`.

I could even use the number and create a date. `select date(now())+interval number day`

Answer (score 0):

- Create a procedure ([`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)) that takes an `INT` parameter.
- In the stored routine, create and populate a temporary table ([`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html), the [`MEMORY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html) engine could be a good choice).
- You'll also need [a `WHILE` loop](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flow-control-statements.html)

All you need to do is put this all together, which should be straightforward for a seasoned MySQL user like you:

```
WHILE counter > 0 DO
    INSERT INTO temptable SELECT counter, DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL count DAY;
    SET counter = counter -1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Well on second thought, you seem to be quite experienced with MySQL, I must be missing the point of your question. Let's wait and see.

Comment: So far this project isn't using any stored procedures. I'd hate to create one just for this, because that would require updates to the database forking and migration tools. (maybe I could create a procedure temporarily) Your answer probably still qualifies as the 'right' answer.